# Dojox enhanced datagrid and spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

How can I use the **enhanced dojox grid** in Spring MVC application?

The `org.springframework.js.resources` jar file seems to have this dojo package.
Can some one suggest links for this implementation?

Comment: Maybe using the [following stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448855/making-dojo-grid-sort-with-spring-and-json) thread or these [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606200/spring-mvc3-with-dojogrid-and-xhrget). The Dojo Docs about REST services is translated inside the Spring world with @ResponseBody annotation just before your controller method and @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=application/json)

Comment: The [Dojo Docs about REST Services](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/data/JsonRestStore#implementing-a-rest-server) and the Spring Reference for RequestMapping with 3.1.2.RELEASE version, which provide the "produces=application/json" attribute.